# нажатие двух кнопок

Tags: java, android

Можно так сделать чтоб действие осуществлялось только после последовательного нажатие на 2 imageButton?

Comment: записыввайте в переменную, что первая кнопка была нажата. А при нажатии второй проверяйте эту переменную.

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно.

1. Создайте на уровне класса активити (фрагмента) переменную-счётчик-нажатий-на-кнопки типа `int`
2. При нажатии на кнопку проверяйте не достигла ли эта переменная значения `1`. Если да - значит вы уже нажали два раза и надо её обнулить. Иначе - увеличьте её на единицу.